# Is there any way to listen to messages without using socket.on?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I don't want to differentiate the clients in my application. So is there any way to listen to messages send by the clients without using socket.on function.

I am looking for something like this.

```
io.sockets.on('new_message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Is this possible to implement with socket.io?

Comment: Have a single function that is defined elsewhere that is called using `.on()` for every connected socket.

Comment: @Qix I was looking for some inbuilt function which is called whenever a user defined event  like 'new_message' is occurred in any one of the sockets.

Comment: No. That's not how it works. The correct way is to apply the same function to the `on('data')` event for each connected socket. This is how sockets work.

Answer (score 0):

An incoming message arrives on a particular socket object.  That's just how it is all implemented.  If you want to listen to all incoming events at the socket.io level, you have to listen to events on all connected sockets, setting an event handler for each new socket as it is connected.

There is likely a place deep in the bowels of the TCP or engine.io implementation where a packet arrives on a socket and it can be logged or seen without regard for which socket it is on, but that is not the public and supported interface that is provided by socket.io.

FYI, what you're asking to accomplish can be done like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('new_message', function(data) {
        // handle message here for each connected socket
    });
});
```